# ggplot, reordering aes and faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

When I try to reorder y-axis based on the value of x and then facet by another variable, the ordering is lost.

Below an example

```
library("ggplot2")

# dummy data_frame
df <- data_frame(subj = as.factor(rep(c("Adam", "Brenna", "Charlie"), each = 3)),
                 type = as.factor(rep(c("A","B", "C"), 3)),
                 score = c(50, 0, 100, rep(c(100, 50, 0), 2)))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
subj    type  score
<fct>   <fct> <dbl>
1 Adam    A        50
2 Adam    B         0
3 Adam    C       100
4 Brenna  A       100
5 Brenna  B        50
```

Plot without faceting and with **only one subj** works well as expected

```
df %>% 
  filter(subj == "Adam") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(score, reorder(type, score))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot without faceting]

and here after faceting by subj

```
   + facet_grid(subj ~., scales = "free_y")
```

[image: faceting]

I did try to reorder also by subj and other approaches for reorder **after** faceting but nothing. I can definitely come with a work around (i.e. create 3 single plots and then combine them together with gridExtra) but  a more elegant way should be available and it seems that I am clearly missing some important details.

Thanks!  :)

Comment: Do you mean you want the y-axis order to be different in each facet?

Comment: Exactly, and I would like it to be ordered by score in each facet. Now, in my data_frame y has many more levels and it would be challenging to reorder it "by hand"

Comment: That would work! thanks @MrFlick